# Math in Java - different results with different objects

Tags: java, math

I'm getting some strange results doing a calculation for the application I'm working on and I thought someone on here might be able to help figure out what's going on.

The requirements for this particular calculation state that the calculation should look like this:

A and B are known

```
A * B = C
```

For this particular calculation

```
A = 0.0410
B = 123456789010
```

Here are the results I'm seeing:

Calculator:

```
0.0410 * 123456789010 = 5061728349.41
```

Java:

B is a double:

```
0.0410f * 123456789010d = 5.061728489223363E9 = 5061728489.223363
```

B is a long:

```
0.0410f * 123456789010l = 5.0617288E9
```

The loss of precision is of less importance to me (I only need 9 digits of precision anyway) than the difference in the 10s and 1s spot. Why does doing the calculation using the double give me the "wrong" result?

Incidentally, I tried doing the calculation using `BigDecimal` and got the same result as I did using a double.

Comment: calculator shows it : `5061728349.41`

Comment: What do you get with two floats?

Comment: @JigarJoshi: yes, and the answer for the 'long' version is also out by an order of magnitude.

Comment: BigDecimal returns 5061728349.41 as expected (if you use the string constructor).

Comment: @Thilo: I can see at least 2 questions where he answered himself after finding the solution. He could mark them as accepted.

Comment: Maybe you can write the code you use for the calcualtion. then it would be obvious how the compiler is interpreting the types of your variables.

Comment: @Thilo - thanks for sticking up for me!

Comment: @Tudor: I definitely could mark those answers as acceptable. I guess I was unaware that it was important to do so when answering my own questions but it makes sense. Thanks for the prod.

Comment: @Joel: Well regardless of who gave the solution it's important to mark it for future readers to find it easily.

Comment: Your two Java outputs are off by a factor of 10, you must have made some mistake.

Comment: @starblue I think you're right. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The various type conversions that happen are specified by the [JLS #5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2). In your case (extract):

> - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.

In `0.0410f * 123456789010d = 506172848.9223363`, `0.0410f` is first converted to a double which is not necessarily equal to `0.0410d`. Actually you can try it and see that is is not:

```
    double d1 = 0.041d;
    double d2 = 0.041f;
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(d1));
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(d2));
```

outputs:

> 0.041000000000000001720845688168992637656629085540771484375
>   0.041000001132488250732421875

In your next example:

```
0.0410f * 123456789010L = 506172832
```

the long is converted to a float, which you can verify with this example:

```
    float f1 = 0.0410f;
    float f2 = 123456789010L;
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(f1)); // 0.041000001132488250732421875
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(f2)); // 123456790528
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.0410f * 123456789010L)); // 5061728768
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(f1 * f2)); // 5061728768
```

As for the precision of float / double operations in general, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937402/moving-decimal-places-over-in-a-double).

Finally, if you use a BigDecimal, you get the correct answer:

```
    BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("0.041");
    BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("123456789010");
    System.out.println(a.multiply(b)); // outputs 5061728349.410
```

Comment: I don't think the float is being converted to a double; I think the conversion is happening after the multiplication. An explicit cast to double before the multiply corrects it.

Comment: @PhilH I have added a reference. When you multiply a float by a double, the float first gets converted to a double.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent description of the problem! Your code examples are really helpful and illustrate the problem. Phil might be right about the conversion to a double happening after the multiplication is completed, but it's a minor detail and a big big help. I have already started redoing my calculations using all BigDecimals.

Comment: @Joel The float does get converted to a double, but that does not change its value - I have reworded that part which was unclear in my initial answer. Basically, `0.041f != 0.041d`.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR Answer: The float cannot represent the 'correct' answer any more exactly. Use a double instead. Also the multiplication will be done inexactly as well without an explicit cast.

Answers I get using http://www.ideone.com

```
  A      B     C      
float  long  float  5061728768.000000
double long  double 5061728489.223363
```

The problem is that the precision of a float is much less than a double, so when multiplied up by a large number (e.g. your 10^10 value) you lose this precision in the multiplication. If we explicitly cast A to a double for the multiplication:

```
double C = ((double)A)*B; //=5061728489.223363
```

Then we get back the additional precision. If we cast the double answer back to a float:

```
float C = (float)((double)((double)A)*B); //=5061728256.000000
```

You see that the answer is different again. The result type of the multiply is used, so in this instance `double`, but the cast back to `float` drops precision. Without an explicit case to double (`double C=A*B`), the `float` type is used. With both casts, the multiply is done as a double, and the precision is lost *after* the multiplication.

Comment: Wow great explanation. There is a lot to consider when doing this type of calculation

Answer (score 1):

The first calculation is using double (64 bits), the second float (32 bits). What you are seeing is "rounding errors".

In both cases it is a floating-point calculation, but in the second case, no "double" arguments are involved, so it just uses 32 bit arithmetic.

Quoting the [Java language spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html):

> If at least one of the operands to a binary operator is of floating-point type, then the operation is a floating-point operation, even if the other is integral.
>
> If at least one of the operands to a numerical operator is of type double, then the operation is carried out using 64-bit floating-point arithmetic, and the result of the numerical operator is a value of type double. If the other operand is not a double, it is first widened (§5.1.5) to type double by numeric promotion (§5.6).
>
> Otherwise, the operation is carried out using 32-bit floating-point arithmetic, and the result of the numerical operator is a value of type float. (If the other operand is not a float, it is first widened to type float by numeric promotion.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is probably in the [Floating point operation section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.4) of the Java Language Specification and in [this older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097694/java-float-int-implicit-conversion). You are probably experiencing rounding errors due to the implicit conversion that is ocurring.

The quote that applies to your situation is

Third operation:

> If at least one of the operands to a binary operator is of
>   floating-point type, then the operation is a floating-point operation,
>   even if the other is integral.

Second operation:

> If at least one of the operands to a numerical operator is of type
>   double, then the operation is carried out using 64-bit floating-point
>   arithmetic, and the result of the numerical operator is a value of
>   type double. If the other operand is not a double, it is first widened
>   (§5.1.5) to type double by numeric promotion (§5.6).

First operation

> Otherwise, the operation is carried out using 32-bit floating-point
>   arithmetic, and the result of the numerical operator is a value of
>   type float. (If the other operand is not a float, it is first widened
>   to type float by numeric promotion.)

Hence, you should not be worried, but decide what is the precision you desire and use the appropriate casting, if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

32-bit IEEE floating point numbers have seven digits of precision; 64-bit allows 16.  That's all you get.  If neither of those is sufficient, you have to use BigDecimal.

This is true in *every* language that implements the IEE standard, not just Java.