# Why isn't 'f' necessary when declaring a non-decimal float in Java?

Tags: java, floating-point, double, primitive-types

If an 'f' suffix is needed when declaring a float in Java because double is the default value, why is it acceptable to not use the 'f' when the float is a non-decimal?

```
float myFloat = 123.45 // not ok because double is the default
float myFloat = 123.45f // ok because the float is explicit

float myFloat = 123 // ok, but why? isn't it still a double by default?
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097694/float-int-implicit-conversion

Comment: Narrowing: double 12345678912344.0 to float, possible loss of near value - not allowed. Widening int 123 to float, float value stays near original value: allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `123` literal is `int` by default, not double. There is no problem to assign an `int` literal to a `float`, since that requires a widening primitive conversion.

When you assign the value of an expression to a variable, the following assignments are allowed :

[JLS 5.2. Assignment contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) :

> Assignment contexts allow the value of an expression to be assigned (§15.26) to a variable; the type of the expression must be converted to the type of the variable.
>
> Assignment contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - **a widening primitive conversion** (§5.1.2)
>
>   ...

[JLS 5.1.2. Widening primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)

> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening
> primitive conversions:
>
> - byte to short, int, long, float, or double
> - short to int, long, float, or double
> - char to int, long, float, or double
> - **int to** long, **float**, or double
>
>   ...

Answer (score 3):

`123` is an `int` value that is promoted to `float` by default as widening conversion.

```
int i = 123;
float f = i;
```

but not vice versa

```
float f = 123;
int i = f; // <-- the compile-time error
```

> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:
>
> ...
>   `int` to `long`, `float`, or `double`
>   ...

[image]