# How to add int through JTextfield input

Tags: java

my code works fine except the fact I cannot obtain an accurate totalBill! Below is my code the area of issue is within the button_1 action. I am sure it is something simple with my math but the outcome for example if I input: 100 (FOR AMOUNT SPENT) 15 (FOR TOTAL TAX AMOUNT) and 10 (FOR TOTAL TIP AMOUNT) comes out to 123, just 2 short of being correct. For the life of me I have retried the fractional math and I am just stumped I am sure it is something relatively easy I just don't see it. Any help is much appreciated.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class unit6_Q2 extends JFrame {

    JPanel main_1 = new JPanel();
    JLabel main_2 = new JLabel();
    JTextField question_1 = new JTextField("Enter amount here",30);
    JTextField question_2 = new JTextField("Enter tax percent here", 30);
    JTextField question_3 = new JTextField("Enter tip amount here", 30);
    JButton button_1 = new JButton("Calculate");

    public unit6_Q2() {
        setTitle("Tutorial");
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400,200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        main_1.add(question_1);
        main_1.add(question_2);
        main_1.add(question_3);

        //if I want the use of enter on each TextField
        /*
        question_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String input_1 = question_1.getText();              
            }
        });

        question_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String input_2 = question_2.getText();
            }
        });
        question_3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String input_2 = question_3.getText();
            }
        });  */

        main_1.add(button_1);
        button_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String input_1 = question_1.getText();  
                String input_2 = question_2.getText();
                String input_3 = question_3.getText();
                int amountSpent = Integer.parseInt(input_1);
                int amountTaxed = Integer.parseInt(input_2);
                int amountTipped = Integer.parseInt(input_3);

                int totalTax = (int)(amountSpent * (amountTaxed*(1/100.0f)));
                int totalTipped =(int)(amountSpent * (amountTipped*(1/100.0f)));
                int totalBill = totalTipped + totalTax + amountSpent;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, totalBill);
            }
        });
        add(main_1);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        unit6_Q2 display = new unit6_Q2();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are truncating fractial data.

```
            int totalTax = (int)(amountSpent * (amountTaxed*(1/100.0f)));
            int totalTipped =(int)(amountSpent * (amountTipped*(1/100.0f)));
```

Use `Math.round()` insteed of `(int)` cast or simply stick to the floating points.

The way you are doing is if lets say totalTax would be 1.9, it will become 1 due to int cast.

Comment: Awesome this fixed the issue. Will mark as correct answer in a few.

Answer (score 1):

Hint, in order to solve such problems, it often helps to "reduce" them to their **core**. In your case: computations. There is absolutely **no need** to add UI complexity. You see ...

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     int amountSpent = Integer.parseInt("100");
     int amountTaxed = Integer.parseInt("15");
     int amountTipped = Integer.parseInt("10");

     int totalTax = (int)( amountSpent * amountTaxed/100.0f );
     System.out.println(totalTax);
     int totalTipped =(int)(amountSpent * amountTipped/100.0f);
     System.out.println(totalTipped);
     int totalBill = totalTipped + totalTax + amountSpent;
     System.out.println(totalBill);
    }
 }
```

Just works (as it avoids the "intermediate" conversion from float to int; which gives you those rounding errors).

So, my answer is more of a strategy how to resolve such problems:

1. Get rid of **anything** that doesn't contribute to the problem. In your case: UI elements and such things
2. Then study the exact rules when doing maths, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097694/float-int-implicit-conversion)

Comment: The UI was required for the assignment. But I appreciate it.

Comment: I am not saying that you avoid the UI. The point is: you dont need the UI code to test your "math" code. To the contrary, trying to build your "house" before you know how to do the groundwork just makes everything more complicted!

Comment: @TheMuffinMan: He's not talking about the assignment but rather the debugging of your problem. It's often better to reduce code, to simplify to get to the root of it. Heed his words, and up-vote his answer as it **is** helpful, if not now, it will help you in the future.